# How do I compress a rather long binary string in Python so that I will be able to access it later?

Tags: python, compression

I have a long array of items (4700) that will ultimately be 1 or 0 when compared to settings in another list. I want to be able to construct a single integer/string item that I can store in some of the metadata such that it can be accessed later in order to uniquely identify the combination of items that goes into it.

I am writing this all in Python. I am thinking of doing something like zlib compression plus a hex conversion, but I am getting myself confused as to how to do the inverse transformation. So assuming bin_string is the string array of 1's and 0's it should look something like this

```
import zlib
#example bin_string, real one is much longer
bin_string="1001010010100101010010100101010010101010000010100101010" 
compressed = zlib.compress(bin_string.encode())
this_hex = compressed.hex()
```

where I can then save this_hex to the metadata. The question is, how do I get the original `bin_string` back from my hex value?  I have lots of Python experience with numerical methods and such but little with compression, so any basic insights would be very valuable.

Comment: Use `zlib.decompress`?

Answer (score 2):

Just do the inverse of each operation. This:

```
zlib.decompress(bytearray.fromhex(this_hex)).decode()
```

will return your original string.

It would be faster and might even result in better compression to simply encode your bits as bits in a byte string, along with a terminating one bit followed by zeros to pad out the last byte. That would be seven bytes instead of the 22 you're getting from `zlib.compress()`. zlib would do better only if there is a strong bias for 0's or 1's, and/or there are repeating patterns in the 0's and 1's.

As for encoding for the metadata, Base64 would be more compact than hexadecimal. Your example would be `lKVKVKoKVQ==`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the .savez_compressed() method of numpy

Convert your simple array into a numpy array amd then use this -

```py
numpy.savez_compressed("filename.npz")
```

Use

```py
numpy.load()
```

To load the .npz file

Comment: This isn't a good solution for me. I can't save this value separately from the other metadata.